# Eclipse : Create a workspace around an existing project

Tags: eclipse, workspace

I have a current existing project repository that has a lot of code that is really old and has a complex file storage structure with a lot of inter dependencies. Until now, an IDE was not being used for development of python scripts and i'm trying to bring that into practice. With Eclipse , i'm assuming that i need to create a workspace for me to be import existing scripts , but the current development process is set up such that we work out of a common location.

For instance , ...../mayadev/python/scripts is a shared folder and all developers work off this location. I'm trying to create an eclipse workspace that is at this /mayadev/python/scripts folder level but i do not want to make additional copies of the existing file. 
So when i import a file system into my workspace, it creates a local copy of all of these files in my workspace. I dont want that to happen . What i would ideally want is to wrap a workspace around that file location, so that i have just a single copy of each file in the shared dev space. I understand this is not a good dev practise, but i'm restricted by a lot of process constraints.

Any insight / advice you might have would be extremely helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing requires the code you work on to be in any sub-directory of your Eclipse workspace.  Create your workspace anywhere (like beneath your home directory); when you create your (Python?) project within the workspace, specify that the project lives in the common development directory.

In the long run, of course, you'll be happier if you put the code in an RCS and have all the developers work on their own copy.  Almost all the RCS's have very good Eclipse integration.